# How can I fulfill a promise with a callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an `async` function that performs an action. I need to wait for that action to complete by listening to an `EventEmitter` event.

In the below example `url` is obtained in the `new` event of the maildev `EventEmitter`. We want to wait for a new mail in order to continue the `async` function.

```
maildev.on('new', callback(mail) { return mail.url })

(async () => {

    await send_semail();
    const url = await // Wait for maildev.on('new', callback(mail)) to be fired
    await visit(url);

})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way one would go about getting a promise resolving callback is using the `Promise` constructor:

```
(async () => {
  await send_semail();
  const { url } = await new Promise(resolve => maildev.on('new', resolve));
  await visit(url);
})()
```

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/) on how to do this more generally for any callback type.

Note that JavaScript function names are typically `camelCased` rather than `snake_cased`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment, this isn't returning the "mail or url". 
How to return datas beyond the promise?

Comment: You can `return` from an async function and then listen to it in another function.

Comment: Doesn't URL get passed to `visit`? If it's not then maildev's `new` event doesn't return an object with a URL property.

Comment: The 'new' event doesn't return an object with an URL property. I simplified the code. This 'new' event returns a "mail" object, which I was parsing inside the callback. Can you give a link to the doc for your code? I'll look how to add code in the callback to return what I want.

Comment: Then the object returned by the `await` is the object the `new` event returns - process it after the `await` to get the URL

Comment: That isn't working, console.log( url ); displays "undefined", but the 'new' event returns an email (I verified with another code)